# Tie via stitching and fencing to GND

Tags: layout, pcb-fabrication, via

I know that via stitching requires me to assign my vias to a signal (like GND pours on top and bottom layers).

Do I need to assign signals to the vias in order to "fence" routed nets, for example, differential lines fenced with GND vias?

Comment: if they're gnd vias, then that's what they're attached to. If they have another net name, then you'll get a drc error.

Comment: @Kartman my question is - do I need to assign the fence vias as the GND or do they need to be by a seperate and unique signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is preferred that the the fence will be assigned to GND.
There is a need to separate between stripline and other srtip structures like microstrip.

In stripline the lines are between GND on top and bottom of the pcb and the vias create a good fence.
on other routhing configurations where the traces are on the top layer, the GND plane is on an inner or bottom layer. there configurations are less resistant to EM interference.